# Import @mdx-js/mdx in a simple typescript nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

**In a very simple node16 typescript 4.8 project, a CLI, I want to use the `@mdx-js/mdx` library, which is distribued as ESM.**

I am a bit lost with all commonJS / ESM / ES2020 vocabulary, sorry ....

My tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "lib": [
            "es2020",
            "es2022"
        ],
        "module": "node16",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "files": [....],
}
```

When doing a naive import : `import { compileSync } from '@mdx-js/mdx';`

I got error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modules/@mdx-js/mdx/index.js from DirDocFileReader.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in DirDocFileReader.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```